# C++ - OpenGL/OpenCV - using a UVMap to map an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

Let's say i have the following image:

[distorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozUfY.jpg)

And i want to apply a UVMap/STMap to undistort it and make it look like this:

[undistorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Gdr.jpg)

Is there a way of doing that using C++ and OpenCV and/or OpenGL? If you could point me to any references/examples it'd be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [undistort](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) and [Remap](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap) in OpenCV.

> The function is simply a combination of initUndistortRectifyMap() (with unity R ) and remap() (with bilinear interpolation). See the former function for details of the transformation being performed.

Remap can do the requested undistortion if you can provide it with the correct mapping.

> The function remap transforms the source image using the specified map:
>   [image: \texttt{dst} (x,y) = \texttt{src} (map_x(x,y),map_y(x,y))]

Comment: So how would i use this UV map with one of those functions? (i put a link because i still don't have enough reputation to include more than 2 links in my original post haha) https://postimg.org/image/7yrp3cp7b/